# Prove: for all integers $x,y\in x+y+xy = 0$ -> $x=y=0 $ or $ x=y=-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

How would you do the proof for this problem?

> Prove that for all integers $x,y$, $(x+y+xy=0)\implies ((x=y=0)\vee(x=y=-2))$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Rewrite the equation as $(x+1)(y+1)=1$.

Comment: But how does that help with the proof?

Comment: How can the product of integers be $1$? There are two options ...

Comment: The product of two integers is $1$ if the two integers are both $1$ or are both $-1$, and in no other way.

Comment: Very clever! +1!

Comment: @Ale: Note that the (standard) idea generalizes a little. For example, $xy+3x+4y=0$ can be rewritten as $(x+4)(y+3)=12$. In a sense this is a variant of completing the square, we are completing a rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\,\ $ Completing a **square** generalizes to completing a **product**

$\qquad \begin{eqnarray} x^2 &+&\ \ \,2bx\quad\ \  &=&\ (x + b)^2 - b^2\\
\iff x\color{#c00}x  &+& bx\!+\!b\color{#c00}x &=\,&  (x+b)(\color{#c00}x+b)-b^2\\
{\rm generalizes\ \ to}\quad   x\color{#c00}y &+&  bx\!+\!b\color{#c00}y\ &=&  (x+b)(\color{#c00}y+b)-b^2\\
{\rm more\ \ generally}\quad  {xy}&\ +\ &bx\! +\! cy &=& \color{}{(x+c)(y+b) - bc}\\ 
\text{your case is }\ b=1=c:\quad {xy}&\,+&\ x +\ y &=& \color{}{(x+1)(y+1) - 1}
\end{eqnarray}$

Applied in your equation we get $\ (x+1)(y+1) = 1,\ $ whose solution is easy, since there are only a couple possible integer factorizations of one to match against the lhs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to factor the equation as (y+1)(x+1) is equal to 1. That means both expressions are either equal to 1 or -1.